# If else loop is skipping if clause [if(2 > 1) ] and moving straight to dead code in the else clause. gRPC instantiation

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, grpc

EDIT: Found the reason why the code was still executing if the loop was changed. I didn't realize the server had to be restarted if alterations were made to other files within the project. The loop's original problem still exists . I Think the reason is the following line due to either incorrect syntax on my part or assinging the variables incorrectly before this line arrives.

```
                if(CapacityService.(CapacityService.MaleWC().getPopulation() >= CapacityService.MaleWC().getCapacity())
```

I'm in the midst of the crunchier end of a gRPC project and I have no idea what is going wrong in this rpc. I am testing the RPC with Bloom and it is continually just executing the final clause and skipping the first one. Had thought it was a gRPC issue but after a lot of editing I tried changing the loop to a guaranteed true just to ensure it was executable and it continued to skip over it.

EDIT:

I am relatively new so I am sure I made some terrible design choices but I can't see anything catastrophically bad. Project was created with Maven for what it is worth.

EDIT. I Have attempted to reduce the code to make it easier to see any issues

```
@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
@Override
    public void mWClock(targetRoom request, StreamObserver<lockStatus> responseObserver) {
    int key = request.getTarget();
    int trigger = 0;
    if (key == 0) {
        do {
            CapacityService.MaleWC().newBuilder()
            .setPopulation(randomInt(5));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(30000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
            //if(2<1)
            if(CapacityService.(CapacityService.MaleWC().getPopulation() >= CapacityService.MaleWC().getCapacity()) {
                CapacityService.MaleWC().newBuilder()
                .setLock(true);
                trigger++;
                //
                String result1 = "Male Bathroom is currently at or over capacity, please wait";
                lockStatus response = lockStatus.newBuilder()
                        .setStatus(result1)
                        .setSpaces(0)
                        .build();
                responseObserver.onNext(response);
                
                
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(30000);Just to delay returns and simulate movement. 
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                CapacityService.MaleWC().newBuilder()
                .setPopulation(randomInt(3));//To reduce it below capacity so the loop continues at while loop
                
            }else {
                //THE CODE THAT EXECUTES
                
                
            }
            //end of do loop
        }while(trigger < 3000);
        responseObserver.onCompleted();
        
        

        
    }else {
        //failure, wrong number entered. TO DO
        responseObserver.onCompleted();
    }

}
```

The MaleWC object is a message from a different services proto being imported here and instantiated at the top. What may possibly be of note is that I was unable to import the proto file where the Room message was created into the proto file with the MWClock service but I don't know if that affects anything. I'm also not overly sure if the static access warning could be causing the issue

```
@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
@Override
    public static Room MaleWC() {
    return Room.newBuilder()
            .setCapacity(3)
            .setPopulation(0)
            .setLock(false)
            .build();
}
```

The server is definitely working from what I can tell. It just keeps jumping to the else clause. Can anyone shed some light? Can share the proto file for the service if it's needed but I'm guessing the proto is fine as it's returning the correct stuff from the else statement, unless the issue was caused by the importing snaffoo mentioned earlier.

Comment: To help people answer, could you reduce the code down to a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Travis Yeah, I'll do my best now to reduce it.

Comment: Also mention why you believe the else clause is being executed (e.g., via  `System.out.println` output).

Comment: @Eric Anderson I'll add what I think the reason is now but it's kind of a shot in the dark

Comment: @System.snort.ln, I was asking for the evidence that shows _that_ the else was being taken. Not any explanation for why it would be taken. So, for example, if you put a println in the else and you see that string in the output logs, that would be the type of evidence I am talking about. I'm not asking for you to run additional experiments; I'm just asking for you to mention the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: @Eric Anderson I was running it in Bloom RPC, only getting the code from the else section irregardless of imput. I'm gonna go back and build something a fair bit less ambitious